# jQuery.getJSON() How to get the Status of a request

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jQuery JavaScript Library **v1.4.2**

I'm using this code

```
var urlToGetToken = 'http://test.com';
        $.getJSON(urlToGetToken, function (data) {
            document.getElementById("demo3").innerHTML = data.access_token;
        }).success(function () {
            alert("second success");
        })
            .error(function () {
            alert("error");
        })
            .complete(function () {
            alert("complete");
        });
```

I would like to print in demo3 the Status code and the Error Message in case the Ajax request fail.

I tired using .error()... but with no success.

Any Ideas?

Comment: If you're using jQuery, why do you use `document.getElementById` ? Just use `$("#demo3").html(data.access_token);`

Comment: You say that you used `.error()` but with no success. Can you give us the code you used for this `error()` call?

Comment: Edit made, thanks for your time on this

Comment: Why don't you upgrade to `1.5` at least?

Comment: getJSON does an ajax request. Unless your "urlToGetToken" is not ready it won't work (I think). And may be your problem is "urlToGetToken" instead of $.getJSON. You can also use $.ajax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Promises/Deferreds are introduced in Jquery 1.5 - 
I am not sure of the syntax you are using in 1.4.2

We can't pass 'failure' call back to $.getJson -
You can Use $.ajax instead - this should definitely work

If you want to tap failure event

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  dataType: 'json',
  data: data,
  success: successCallback,
  error : failureCallback
}); 

var successCallback = function(data){
$("#demo3").innerHTML = data.access_token;
};

var failureCallback  = function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
$("#demo3").innerHTML = "Your error message"; 
};
```

Comment: Interesting, in this case how do I get the status of the request?

Comment: @GibboK would you mind looking at the API documentation for `$.ajax`?

Comment: @Gibbok - This is not documented and I am not sure what could be the possible values for 'textStatus', you can use the combination of the 'textStatus' and 'errorThrown' to show your error message - for text status AFAIK the possible values are "timeout"
"error",
"notmodified",
"success",
"parsererror"

Answer (score 2):

As `$.getJSON` is ajax request to find the error msg use this:

```
$(document).ajaxError(function(event, msg, settings){
  alert(msg);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

From the docs:

```
jQuery.getJSON( url [, data] [, success(data, textStatus, jqXHR)] )
```

So:

```
$.getJSON(urlToGetToken, function (data) {
    document.getElementById("demo3").innerHTML = textStatus;
}).success(function () {
```

Will provide you with the result.

Comment: I don't think `XMLHttpRequest` has the `success` method (bug present in original code).